# WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it

Tags: web, nginx, php, xenforo

I'm getting this error:

```
WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it
```

When trying to access my XenForo installation at forums.domain.com in my PHP error log.

It happens every time, and I think it's causes PHP to crash, which prevents the other site on the same box from working as well.

I'm using nginx with two server blocks for these two sites. One's under new. and one's under forums..

Thanks.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Configure your Pool `pm.*` directives & reload/restart PHP - http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php

```
pm.max_children int

The number of child processes to be created when pm is set to static and the maximum number of child processes to be created when pm is set to dynamic. This option is mandatory.

This option sets the limit on the number of simultaneous requests that will be served. Equivalent to the ApacheMaxClients directive with mpm_prefork and to the PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN environment variable in the original PHP FastCGI.
```

Comment: This answer needs more explanation, such as which setting and where to find it, how to change it.

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu 12 (and probably elsewhere), the `pm.max_children` value is set in the configuration file `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`. Search the file for that string and increase the value. Restart PHP for the change to take effect with this command:

```
 sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

If you are using Apache, you may need to restart that service first.

Comment: Same for 7.4: `grep -s 'max_children' /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/{*,.*}`
`/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:;   static  - a fixed number (pm.max_children) of child processes;`